# custom domain mapping for azure mvc role works for main page

Tags: azure, dns, azure-worker-roles, domain-name

Recently I have tried to bind custom domain name to azure web role.

I am able to view home page of my myapp.cloudapp.net site with my.domain, but when I try to go by any link **/Controller/Action**  redirect fails. When I try manual type address as Azure MVC role - **my.domain/....**  my registrant say me this page not exists.What configuration should I apply to fix this (if this is related to azure). I have used [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/) guide. I have specified

```
  CNAME www --> myapp.cloudapp.net

  Url Pointer --> http://myapp.cloudapp.net
```

Something else? Thanks.

**Update**

```
   From technical support:

   Hello, 

   I was able to replicate the issue. It appears like when you stealth redirect your 
   domain 'my.domain' http://app.cloudapp.net/ is using some frame breaker  
   code to restrict the access to http://app.cloudapp.net/Account/Login . 
   I suggest you to contact administrators of app://app.cloudapp.net/ regarding the issue. 

   I have tested by stealth redirecting domain 'my.domain' some other URL and it worked fine. 

   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need is the CNAME record for "www".  Remove the URL pointer and if your domain registrar allows forwarding, then forward the root domain to www.customdomain.com

Comment: removing pointer doesnt resolve issue.instead I am not able rich even home page.